# Reading and loading multiple Excel sheets in R

Tags: r, excel, readxl

I want to read and load an Excel file into my environment, I'm just getting a list.

```
path <- "data/data.xlsx"

path %>% 
  excel_sheets() %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map(read_excel, path = path)
```

Comment: try `df <- read_excel( path )`

Comment: Are you trying to read multiple files into R or just a single one? From the last line in your code it is a bit unclear which?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:
For this example i made a xlsx with 3 sheets.

```
library(readxl)
# Get the sheets count
sheets <- excel_sheets("some.xlsx")

for (i in 1 : length(sheets)) {

 shts <- paste("x", i, sep = ".")
 # Read every single sheet and assign to variable x1, x2, x3 etc...
 assign(shts, read_excel("c:/Temporal/TEST.xlsx", sheet=sheets[i]))
}
```

Result:

[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: This works great for loading multiple sheets but is there an easy way to add the sheet name to the dataframe?